# Visual Studio include path precedence

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After spending a couple of hours trying to fathom why I was getting a compile error on the call to new in afxtempl.h, having exhausted other solutions found via google I realised there was a local new.h causing the problem (when I say local, I mean it was in one of a few dozen projects that make up the solution).

This took a while to find because I'm only vaguely familiar with the code base and wasn't expecting to find a new.h, but also because I wouldn't have thought this would interfere with the angle bracketed

```
#include <new.h>
```

in afxtempl.h. I've always been under the impression that

```
#include <file.h>
```

meant look in system includes first.

Looking at the include path from an offending project all I have (other than a couple of local paths that don't actually exist on my machine) are:

```
$(VC_IncludePath)
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
```

So given new.h is (was) in a different project how did it get picked up?

I should probably add at this point that the solution has just been migrated from VC++ 6 to VS 2013.

The local new.h doesn't #define _INC_NEW by the way, or define/declare new. The name is just coincidental, it has nothing to do with memory allocation.

I'm just curious if there's some include setting I'm unaware of and would prefer not to have a similarly frustrating few hours in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle brackets includes are searched in in per-project additional include directories (`C/C++ - General - Additional Include Directories`) first. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) behavior:

> Angle-bracket form
>
> The preprocessor searches for include files in this order:
>
> - Along the path that's specified by each /I compiler option.
> - When compiling occurs on the command line, along the paths that are specified by the INCLUDE environment variable.
>
> ...
>
> For example, the command
>
> ```
> CL /ID:\MSVC\INCLUDE MYPROG.C
> ```
>
> causes the preprocessor to search the directory D:\MSVC\INCLUDE\ for include files such as STDIO.H.

It seems your project directory is added to additional include directories list. You can see all command line options passed to the compiler at `C/C++ - CommandLine` tab in project settings.

This is usual way C/C++ compilers work, see for instance [g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) documentation:

> ```
> #include <file>
> ```
>
> This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can *prepend* directories to this list with the -I option (see Invocation).

So, I am afraid there is no way to change this behavior if you want to keep addtional include directories list. As workaround you can place include files in the subdirectory of project root and add project root to additional directories list, so your includes would look like `#include "project/new.h"`, this will require code restructure though.